# How to install R packages when Onedrive syncronizes your documents folder

Tags: r, onedrive, install.packages

At my work they have had the horrible idea to force Onedrive on everyone. Now I can no longer install R packages because Onedrive has take over the default installation folder. Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Error message:

```
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/XXXX/OneDriveAtWorkplace/Dokumenter": Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet
```

Unfortunately I am not in a position where I can turn off Onedrive. But there must be a way to set another default folder for packages to be installed in.

Comment: What version of R are you using? The newer versions don't use your user home directory so it's usually not affected by OneDrive issues as easily. Otherwise you can customize your libPaths to use any directory you like. You probably want to set that in a .RProfile file. See `?Startup` for more details

Comment: I just installed the newest version of R as of today

Comment: I don't know where or how you installed it. So it's helpful for future reference to give a specific version number to make it clear. Like R 4.2.0 or something like that.

Comment: You can change/set the location for installation folders.

Comment: But how? I have tried adding location to install.packages, but it still gets the same issue.